# Combine slash separated words to form a string in Python

Tags: python, list, nlp

I would like to find a way to combine slash separated words from a list of strings. Here's an example:

```
string1 = 'awesome/stupid'
string2 = 'red/blue/yellow' 
string3 = 'car'


def some_func(string1, strin2):

.
.
.
```

Output:

```
'awesome red car'
'awesome blue car'
'awesome yellow car'    
'stupid red car'
'stupid blue car'
'stupid yellow car'
```

What I've tried splitting by '/' and adding strings, but the loop ends up being too big. The solution I'm looking for is for a general case, where I don't know the amount of words separated by slashs.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: will string3 be of one word

Comment: stackoverflow is not a code-writing service, try it yourself and come back if something specific goes wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

strings = [string1, string2, string3]    # Put all your slash-separated strings here
for x in product(*(s.split('/') for s in strings)):
    print(' '.join(x))
```

Comment: I posted the same solution without realising you answered! Thank you, that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @PepeMoreno no problem, you should consider marking your own answer as correct as well :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself using itertools.product(*args)

```
string1 = ['awesome/stupid','red/blue/yellow','car']
s = [x.split('/') for x in string]
```

Output:

```
[['awesome', 'stupid'], ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'], ['car']]
```

Then

```
import itertools

prod = list(itertools.product())
prod
```

Output:

```
[('awesome', 'red', 'car'),
('awesome', 'blue', 'car'),
('awesome', 'yellow', 'car'),
('stupid', 'red', 'car'),
('stupid', 'blue', 'car'),
('stupid', 'yellow', 'car')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using loops in a naive way:

```
string1 = 'awesome/stupid'
string2 = 'red/blue/yellow' 
string3 = 'car'

for x in string1.split('/'):
    for y in string2.split('/'):
        print(f'{x} {y} {string3}')

# awesome red car
# awesome blue car                                              
# awesome yellow car                                          
# stupid red car                                              
# stupid blue car                                             
# stupid yellow car
```

Comment: Thank you Austin, but I wanted a general solution, for an unknown number of strings and slash separated words. I just posted what I consider the best solution. Still, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
string1 = 'awesome/stupid'
string2 = 'red/blue/yellow' 
string3 = 'car'

def(str1,str2,str3):
    list1=str1.split("/")
    list2=str2.split("/")
    list3=str3.split("/")
    for i in list1:
       for j in list2:
           for k in list3:
               print(i,j,k)
```

**Output**

```
'awesome red car'
'awesome blue car'
'awesome yellow car'    
'stupid red car'
'stupid blue car'
'stupid yellow car'
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thank you, but I meant for a general case, with n strings and m words. I just posted the solution I found, but thanks for the help anyway.